After installing Python 3.12.7 from 3.9.1 I got this issue. Numpy version has been altered and I received this error
I tried to incorporate tensorflow 2.0 into anaconda to be used in jupyter notebook. However, numerous issues have arise ranging from no module tensorflow detected to uninstall and reinstall anaconda. This then followed by a successful pip install and then a different version of Python, updating it from 3.9.1 to 3.12.7. Now the numpy packages don't work anymore and become unusable.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

A module that was compiled using NumPy 1.x cannot be run in
NumPy 2.1.3 as it may crash. To support both 1.x and 2.x
versions of NumPy, modules must be compiled with NumPy 2.0.
Some module may need to rebuild instead e.g. with 'pybind11>=2.12'.

If you are a user of the module, the easiest solution will be to
downgrade to 'numpy<2' or try to upgrade the affected module.
We expect that some modules will need time to support NumPy 2.


For now you can do:
pip install "numpy<2.0"

or
pip install numpy=1.26.4

